# Central manifold theorem => Stable/unstable manifold?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, manifolds, dynamical-systems

I'm a bit confused why we always separate the stable/unstable manifold theorem and the central manifold theorem.

The stable/unstable manifold theorem applies to a hyperbolic point ($\mathrm{Re}(\lambda)\neq 0$) and states (roughly) that there is a unique stable manifold and a unique unstable manifold, the dimensions of which corresponds to the dimensions of the stable and unstable manifolds, repectively.

The center manifold states that there is a stable and an unstable manifold, unique, and a (possibly non-unique) center manifold, the dimension of which is the dimension of the center subspace (it of course also states other things which are not of interested here).

**Question**: Is there additional information is the stable/unstable manifold theorem that is not included in the center manifold theorem, applied to the particular case when the dimension of the central manifold equals to $0$?

Comment: I don't think so, if the centre manifold is of dimension zero, then you have the common results of stable/unstable manifold theory. I must remark though that centre manifolds are very important as the dynamics there are given by the nonlinear terms of your system. Furthermore, centre manifolds are very useful, for example: 1) in singular perturbation problems, or the so called slow-fast systems; 2) In normal form theory; and related to it, 3) In reducing the dimension of the problem you are studying.